# Difference between sum of odd integers and positive integers

Tags: sequences-and-series

> $S_1$ is the sum of positive integers from $1$ to $k$ inclusive.
>
> $S_2$ is the sum of the odd positive integers from $1$ to $2k+1$ inclusive.
>
> Given that $S_2-S_1=55$, find the value of k.

I tried this with expanding with the formulas for $\sum_{r=1}^{k}=\frac{1}{2}k(k+1)$ etc :

$$\begin{align}\sum_{r=1}^{2k+1}{(2r-1)-\sum_{r=1}^{k}{r}}&=55\\\implies \frac{7}{2}k^2+\frac{7}{2}k-54&=0\end{align}$$

Which means $k$ isn't an integer... Is there something wrong with the "inclusive" statement and the top bound of the sum maybe?

Comment: Your $S_2$ is incorrect.

Comment: @Micah So instead this? $$\begin{align}\sum_{r=1}^{2k-1}{(2r-1)-\sum_{r=1}^{k}{r}}&=55\\\implies \frac{7}{2}k^2-\frac{9}{2}k-54&=0\end{align}$$ and $k$ isn't an integer either

Comment: @AnthonyML: See David's answer -- the upper limit of your first sum is also incorrect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $S_2$, you wrote
$$ \sum_{r=1}^{2k+1}(2r-1), $$
which says to add up the first $2k + 1$ odd numbers.
The smallest term in the sum is $1$ and the largest is
$2(2k + 1) - 1 = 4k + 1$.

But $2k+1$ is the largest odd number you are supposed to include in $S_2$.
So your expression for $S_2$ gives you a result that is generally much greater than it should be.

The expression $2r - 1$ gives you an odd number for every integer $r$ and gives the correct first term ($2r - 1 = 1$) when $r = 1$.
Your problem is at the other end of the summation.
What should be the last value of $r$ in order to ensure that $2k+1$ is the last term in the sum?

As a hint, there are actually only $k + 1$ terms in the sum
$$ 1 + 3 + 5 + \cdots + (2k + 1). $$

Answer (score 1):

A very useful trick to this problem is that the sum of the first $k$ odd integers is simply $k^2$. Then we have:

$S_1(k) = k(k+1)/2$
$S_2(k) = (k+1)^2$

$S_2(k)−S_1(k)=55$
$(k+1)^2 - k(k+1)/2=55$
$k^2/2 + (3 k)/2 - 54 = 0$
$k=-12$ or $k=9$

So our final answer is $k=9$.

Comment: Then use the fact that $k$ is a positive integer to conclude.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

\begin{align*}
S_2&=1 + 3 + 5 + \dots + (2k+1)\\
S_1&=0 + 1 + 2 + \dots + k
\end{align*}

Both of these sums have $k+1$ terms.

Subtracting the $r$th term of the second sum from the $r$th term of the first sum gives the $k+1$-term sum

$$
S_2-S_1=1 + 2 + \dots + (k+1)
$$

and you should be able to recognize $55$ as a triangular number.